# Xcode Interface Builder glitch with UIImageView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder

In Interface Builder, when I add an UIImageView and set its content mode to "center", while viewing it in Interface Builder the @2x version of the image is shown, but it is shown 4 times too large. It is only a visible thing in the Interface Builder, because when I run the app it looks okay.

Is this an Xcode bug, or am I missing something?

**Background:**
In my experience, in older versions of Xcode, Interface Builder would always show the @1x version of images, even if there is a @2x or @3x version. This changed with an update a couple of versions ago.

The problem does not occur if the content mode is set to one of the scaling types (which is kind of logical), but does occur when content mode is set to center, top, bottom, top left, etc...

Again, the problem only appears while in Interface Builder. In the simulator, or on a device, the images are shown as one would expect them.

Most of the time I would use "Scale to Fill" as content mode, but in some cases I need one that is set to "center".

I am running Xcode 11.3.1. The problem started a couple of updates ago. I was under the impression that it was a Xcode bug, but since it has not been addressed a couple of updates later I am beginning to wonder.

[image]

**note:** : Turns out that this problem does not occur if I use the asset catalog to manage the image. The problem does occur if I just add the 3 image files to the project.

Comment: How is the image stored in your app project, and how is it referenced in IB? “but since it has not been addressed a couple of updates later” What is the feedback number of your bug report to Apple? And what is your question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing. Take a look at this image: https://i.imgur.com/A6tU3Es.png (it's big)... From left to right: iPhone 8 / iPhone 11 Pro / iPad Pro 9.7" and Xcode behind them. `@2x` and `@3x` versions displayed as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had added the 3 image files ( image.png , image@2x.png, image@3x.png ) to the project as files. The old way of doing this. Turns out that when I combine the three images into an image set in the asset catalog the problem is solved. Now I am not sure if the method of adding files the old way is still supposed to work, or if using the asset catalog is the only proper way to add an image to a project. Apple documentation suggests the image catalog is optional.

Comment: @ArnovanGoch - quick testing... image sets *outside* the asset catalog ***are*** loaded and displayed properly at runtime. It's only in IB that they are not.